# multiple connections in 1 project with sftp (sublime text 2)

Tags: sublimetext2, sftp, sublimetext

I need to have 2 ftp connections in a sublime project. 1 for the testing server, 1 for production environment.

Is that possible? And if yes - how?

Comment: Sorry! "Add alternate remote mapping" is the solution!

Comment: Please post your answer and accept it in case anyone else needs it. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

right click to to folder you want to remote map > sftp/ftp > Add alternate remote mapping.

When there are 2 remote mappings, below the 'add ...' you can switch between these mappings.

Comment: Is it possible to post to these two mappings simultaneously?

Comment: Is there any shortcut to switch between these two mappings?